# How to type a curly brace ("{") in CyanogenMod 13?

Tags: cyanogenmod, keyboard

By chance, I got hold of a Samsung Galaxy S III (S3) Mini, rooted it, and upgraded it to CyanogenMod 13 (Android 6.0.1). When trying to connect it to my WiFi network, I could not do so because my WiFi password contains a curly brace, and it seems I can't type that with the virtual keyboard.

I am quite sure there is a way to do that, so how to type a curly brace in CM 13's AOSP keyboard? Should I install another keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**On Samsung keyboard:**

Touch `Sym`, then `1/2` the curly braces are under 7 and 8.

**On AOSP Keybord, Google Keyboard, Gboard:**

Touch `?123`,  then `=\<` you'll get all symbols there.